# Extract an unknown amount of strings between 2 specific strings in R

Tags: r

I have the following line of strings:
" French base"
"Cleaver"
"Crust"
"There is"

I want to extract all lines between "French base" and "There is" using R. 
Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: You are probably looking for `x[(which(x == "French base") + 1):(which(x == "There is") - 1)]`.

Comment: Your data set : `data <- c("French base" ,"Cleaver" ,"Crust" ,"There is")` and your condition vector:  `look <- c("French base","There is")` . Then `data[!(data %in% look)]`gives what you expect.